# GMOD Overriding models to render above props/maps?

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I am trying to make a specific player render above everything else.
I've tried to do multiple things, including using ClientsideModel(), DrawModel() and stuff like that to no avail.
If someone could help, that'd be nice! I couldn't find anyone else asking this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is expected that you have researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a summary of what you have tried and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I once did this by accident... Let me search for my old code. will post an answer when I found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use the player's [`HUDPaint`](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/GM/HUDPaint) rather than a model draw, as that's called last. So we can start with:

```
hook.Add("HUDPaint", "playerOverride", function()

end)
```

This is a 2D Rendering context, so we need to start a 3D one, which is easy enough with [`cam.start3D()`](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/cam/Start3D)

```
hook.Add("HUDPaint", "playerOverride", function()
    cam.Start3D()
    cam.End3D()
end)
```

Then of course, we just draw the target model with [`Entity:DrawModel()`](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Entity/DrawModel)

```
hook.Add("HUDPaint", "playerOverride", function()
    cam.Start3D()
        target:DrawModel()
    cam.End3D()
end)
```

The above code assumes you've got a target in mind, which you can either set `target` to, or replace it.

If you'd prefer to apply this to everyone, *(I do hope you're not writing wallhacks)*, then you can loop through the list of players with [`player.getAll()`](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/player/GetAll)

```
hook.Add("HUDPaint", "playerOverride", function()
    cam.Start3D()
        for k,v in pairs(player.GetAll()) do
            if v ~= LocalPlayer() then -- Make sure we don't redraw ourselves
                v:DrawModel()
            end
        end
    cam.End3D()
end)
```

(Note, I'm not able to test this just at the moment, but I'm fairly confident in it)

Comment: Late response, sorry but I already ended up getting it a while ago. I'll accept your answer since it is correct.